# Программа решает уравнение тремя способами. Как построить график по данным полученным этими способами?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, график

Программа решает уравнение тремя способами.Как по данными, полученным этими способами построить график?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# * - coding: utf-8 - *-
# импорт математической библиотеки
from math import *
x_0=float(input("Введите начальное значение x"))
x_k=float(input("Введите конечное значение x"))
n_1=int(input("Введите число разбиений"))
y_0=float(input("Введите начальное значение y"))
def du (x_0,y_0):
    return  1/(cos(x_0))-y_0*tan(x_0)
h= (x_k-x_0) /n_1
#Аналитический метод
for i in range (0,n_1):
   y3=cos(x_0)+sin(x_0)
   print("Аналитический метод", y3)
#Метод Эйлера
for i in range (0,n_1):
   y1=y_0+h*du (x_0,y_0)
   x1=x_0+h
   x_0=x1
   y_0=y1
   print("euler", y1)
# метод рунге-кутта
for i in range (0,n_1):
    k1=h*du (x_0,y_0)
    k2=h*du (x_0+h/2,y_0+k1/2)
    k3=h*du (x_0+h/2,y_0+k2/2)
    k4=h*du (x_0+h,y_0+k3)
    y1=y_0+ (k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4) /6
    x_0=x_0+h
    y_0=y1
    print("Runge-kutta", y1)
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы нарисовать график двумерной функции передайте [plt.plot()](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) массив `X`-ов и массив `Y`-ов одинаковой длины:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def my_func(x):
    return np.cos(x) + np.sin(x)**2

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
y = my_func(x)


plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пробывал делать по такому принципу, но как мы можем составить массив из X?Если для Y мы после решения просто можем приписать например ylist.append(y3),то как быть с x, если он вводиться пользователем.

Comment: @SunnyDayXO, `x = np.linspace(x_0, x_k, n_1)`

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @SunnyDayXO, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814) и/или [проголосовать за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) ;)

Comment: @MaxU жаль ответ не принят а решение хорошое